# Meaning of the following Summation notation in graph theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I've been reading the paper by Bayati on the sequential algorithm for generating random graphs.
But I ran across a notation I've not encountered before and was wondering if some can help me make sense of it. Suppose we encounter the following:

$\sum_{i\sim_G j}d_id_j$

Where $d_i$ is the degree of vertex $i$, $G$ is some fixed graph. So now what am I exactly iterating over ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $i\sim_G j$ is sometimes used to indicate that $i$ and $j$ are adjacent in $G$. So this sum would iterate over the edges of the graph $G$.

EDIT: There is some minor ambiguity here. It may also iterate over each vertex $i$, and then its neighbors $j$, in which case the sum iterates over each edge twice. Without context it's not clear to me which of these it should be, but I lean towards the double counting one.

Comment: +1 for double counting.

Comment: So that notation is just a convenient way to say "perform depth first search"